# Custom list reordering animation in Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, html-lists, flip

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm really enjoying Vue so far.
I would like to animate the reordering of items in a list and used a `transition-group` to do so. It works, but I find that having the items overlap each other during the FLIP animation makes for a confusing result: It's difficult to grasp what went up or down and by how much.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#flip-list-demo',
  data: {
    items: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function () {
      this.items = _.shuffle(this.items)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
    <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way (e.g. some CSS) to have the items deviate a little bit to the left/right as they move up/down? Ideally by a distance proportional to the length of the move (i.e. number of ranks gained/lost)?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue list animation with Greensock JS hooks: wait for leave to finish before enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004995/vue-list-animation-with-greensock-js-hooks-wait-for-leave-to-finish-before-ente)

Comment: I don't see the link with my question tbh, but it might be because I'm new to all this. I'm not using Greensock and I'm specially looking at "reordering" transitions (not creation/deletion). Specifically also, I need to have the additional sideways movement proportional to the vertical movement.